# tkinter wiget.bind('<Activate>', callback) not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to create a message box when a button turns from disabled to active but when the button actually turns from disabled to active for some reason my callback is not even being called I've tried to get it working so for quite a bit of time now and I'm stuck.

**Here is an example of the problem:**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk



def disable_and_activate():
    b.config(state  = DISABLED)
    b.config(state = ACTIVE)


def is_working(event):
    print('working')

root = Tk()

b = Button (root, text = 'click me', command = disable_and_activate)
b.pack()


b.bind('<Activate>', is_working)


root.mainloop()
```

**Console:**

the button is clicked but there's nothing printed on the console

Comment: Try adding `root.update()` between the 2 `.config`s

Comment: i tried but still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Activate>` event is not triggered when you set the state of the button to `"active"`. The event is triggered when the window becomes the active window.

For example, when I run your code on my OSX machine, if I click on some other application to give it focus and then I click back to the tkinter window, the event will fire when the tkinter window becomes the active window.

This is explained in the [canonical tcl/tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/bind.htm#M8) which says this:

> **Activate**, **Deactivate**
> These two events are sent to every sub-window of a toplevel when they change state. In addition to the focus Window, the Macintosh platform and Windows platforms have a notion of an active window (which often has but is not required to have the focus). On the Macintosh, widgets in the active window have a different appearance than widgets in deactive windows. The **Activate** event is sent to all the sub-windows in a toplevel when it changes from being deactive to active. Likewise, the **Deactive** event is sent when the window's state changes from active to deactive. There are no useful percent substitutions you would make when binding to these events.

Answer (score 1):

Here the problem was just the code inside the function , It seems like you needed to call `EventGenerate('<<Activate>>')` I also recommend adding 2 << and 2 >>

So I rewrote the code and its now working perfectly fine:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk
import tkinter



def disable_and_activate():
        b.configure(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
        b.configure(state=tkinter.ACTIVE)
        b.event_generate("<<Activate>>")


def is_working(event):
    print('working')

root = Tk()

b = Button (root, text = 'click me', command = disable_and_activate)
b.pack()


b.bind('<<Activate>>', is_working)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: there is an Activate event at least from this [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20190512164300id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/event-types.html)  and  also from this [website](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-event-binding/) plus I need to create the message box right after the button has been activated not when the button is clicked, but thanks for your answer

Comment: There is definitely an `Activate` event. Here's where it is mentioned in the canonical documentation: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/bind.htm#M8

Comment: Problem Solved now  Hope It helps !

Comment: Just to be clear, `<<Activate>>` has nothing to do with the built-in `<Activate>` event or the activation of a widget.  You could use any word you want instead of `<<Activate>>` (eg: `<<MyEvent>>`) and it would work just as well.